# Asked a question on code and received an applicable answer for Server Fault

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

Recently I asked a question on PowerShell scripting. The idea was to set the execution policies across an entire network using a script.

Another user answered my question (with comment), however, it wasn't to fix my code but rather link to external site. This was a perfectly adequate solution for me. Here is the post for more information.

[Set-ExecutionPolicy for hundreds of users with PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099100/set-executionpolicy-for-hundreds-of-users-with-powershell-script)

How should we handle this question? Should comment be somehow converted to answer? Anything else?

We were considering to close the question with out posting an answer, thus the user would get no credit. But, the question would still exist for future users.

Comment: To clarify, I posted a comment as opposed to an answer, because the answer would be link-only. Closing the question without any answers will likely lead to it being deleted eventually (if I understand the process correctly).

Comment: @briantist It's not link-only if you add excerpts from the link in your answer.

Comment: @approxiblue true it just seems a bit off-topic since the answer wouldn't be code-related, it would be group policy instructions..

Comment: You could flag your question for migration, hop in chat and request users close the question as a migration to the target site (not applicable in this case because server fault is not in the standard migration target list), or just delete it and re-ask it on the target site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting the link to a proper answer seem to be valid for this case.

Since the question is on-topic for SO than valid answer (link + summary) is fine in this case.

Not every programming question must have only programming solutions. This particular question is not just asking to fix the code, but have practical goal that could be achieved with the demonstrated code - so both types of answers "why code does not work" and "here is another solution" are acceptable.

It is fine for "why this code does not work" questions to have "don't do {this} at all, use {that} instead" answer (most common case: Q:"why {SQL injection sample} does not work" - A:"use parametrized queries").

Alternatives if you need more information:

- question can be split into "why code does not work" (SO) and "how to change policy" (SF), but unless you have practical interest why your code did not work SO part probably not worth it.
- you can flag for migration to SF or just re-ask there (delete on SO). It is likely that there are similar questions already - make sure to search for them first.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the answer.